# findstr command with pipe in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have tried following command to get the list of text files.

```
   "%svn%" list "%Path%" -R | findstr /c:".txt" > TxtFile_List.txt
```

But it shows "'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command," Error...

Comment: Try the full path to `findstr`

Comment: please tell us the content of "%svn%" and "%Path%". i think there are quotes or pipes in the variables that are interpreted by cmd.

Comment: SET svn=D:\Tools\svn\bin\svn.exe and set Path=svn://127.0.0.1:6140/svn/MirrorDB_Dec25/trunk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `set Path=svn://127.0.0.1:6140/svn/MirrorDB_Dec25/trunk` you are overwriting the system's `PATH` variable. Therefore `findstr.exe` is not found any longer. You should consider using a different variable name.